# Android upgrade sqlite database issue

Tags: android, database, upgrade

I have a little issue with upgrading my sqlite database. For now I'm using this :

```
@Override
public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
    Log.w("","UPGRADE DATABASE : "+" oldVErsion : "+oldVersion+" newVersion : "+newVersion);
    switch(newVersion){
    case 2:
        Log.w("","UPGRADE DATABASE : "+newVersion);
        db.execSQL("ALTER TABLE collection_lang ADD COLUMN bonus_text VARCHAR(200)");
        db.execSQL("ALTER TABLE collection_lang ADD COLUMN quantity integer");
    case 3:
        Log.w("","UPGRADE DATABASE : "+newVersion);
        db.execSQL("ALTER TABLE users ADD COLUMN firstName varchar(70)");
        db.execSQL("ALTER TABLE users ADD COLUMN lastName varchar(70)");
        db.execSQL("ALTER TABLE users ADD COLUMN user varchar(70)");
    }
}
```

It's working if you already have the application installed from the beggining..but if you install it now, it will run queries only in `case 3`, because the current version is 3.

I need to find a way to run the queries from the beginning.. if my last version of database is 5, I want to run first the case 2, than case 3, than 4 and at last case 5. So I won't need to write all the queries from the beginning because it will crash for the old users.

Any ideas how to achieve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just add your queries from the case 2 into the case 3 and add break statement after each case. So in your case it will be something like this:

```
@Override
public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
    Log.w("","UPGRADE DATABASE : "+" oldVErsion : "+oldVersion+" newVersion : "+newVersion);
    switch(newVersion){
    case 2:
        Log.w("","UPGRADE DATABASE : "+newVersion);
        db.execSQL("ALTER TABLE collection_lang ADD COLUMN bonus_text VARCHAR(200)");
        db.execSQL("ALTER TABLE collection_lang ADD COLUMN quantity integer");
        break;
    case 3:
        Log.w("","UPGRADE DATABASE : "+newVersion);
        db.execSQL("ALTER TABLE collection_lang ADD COLUMN bonus_text VARCHAR(200)");
        db.execSQL("ALTER TABLE collection_lang ADD COLUMN quantity integer");
        db.execSQL("ALTER TABLE users ADD COLUMN firstName varchar(70)");
        db.execSQL("ALTER TABLE users ADD COLUMN lastName varchar(70)");
        db.execSQL("ALTER TABLE users ADD COLUMN user varchar(70)");
        break;
    }
}
```

**Update:** Do smthg like this:

```
switch(newVersion){
case 2:
    Log.w("","UPGRADE DATABASE : "+newVersion);
    db.execSQL("ALTER TABLE collection_lang ADD COLUMN bonus_text VARCHAR(200)");
    db.execSQL("ALTER TABLE collection_lang ADD COLUMN quantity integer");
    break;
case 3:
    Log.w("","UPGRADE DATABASE : "+newVersion);
    switch(oldVersion) {
        case 1:
            db.execSQL("ALTER TABLE collection_lang ADD COLUMN bonus_text VARCHAR(200)");
            db.execSQL("ALTER TABLE collection_lang ADD COLUMN quantity integer");
            db.execSQL("ALTER TABLE users ADD COLUMN firstName varchar(70)");
            db.execSQL("ALTER TABLE users ADD COLUMN lastName varchar(70)");
            db.execSQL("ALTER TABLE users ADD COLUMN user varchar(70)");
            break;
        case 2: 
            db.execSQL("ALTER TABLE users ADD COLUMN firstName varchar(70)");
            db.execSQL("ALTER TABLE users ADD COLUMN lastName varchar(70)");
            db.execSQL("ALTER TABLE users ADD COLUMN user varchar(70)");
            break;
    }

}
```

Comment: I've already tried this..but there is another problem. If it's fresh install, the new user will get directly to version 3, which is correct..but if user already have the second version of database, and when he tries to upgrade to version 3 it will throw him exception,because he already have `bonus_text` and `quantitiy` columns.

Answer (score 2):

What about to use a loop?

```
       //or start = oldVersion;              
 for (int start = 2 , start<=newVersion ; start++){
      switch(start){
    case 2:
        Log.w("","UPGRADE DATABASE : "+newVersion);
        db.execSQL("ALTER TABLE collection_lang ADD COLUMN bonus_text VARCHAR(200)");
        db.execSQL("ALTER TABLE collection_lang ADD COLUMN quantity integer");
        break;
    case 3:
        Log.w("","UPGRADE DATABASE : "+newVersion);
        db.execSQL("ALTER TABLE users ADD COLUMN firstName varchar(70)");
        db.execSQL("ALTER TABLE users ADD COLUMN lastName varchar(70)");
        db.execSQL("ALTER TABLE users ADD COLUMN user varchar(70)");
        break;
    default:
        break;
    }
```

**But It is not normal way. As if a user already added some alteration. And you again run that alteration then it will create exception.**

Comment: It will not work in case if you have oldVersion = 3 and newVersion = 4. To work in general case in your head of the cycle you should make: int start = oldVersion.

Comment: I think your approach is harder to understand but it's prettier then mine.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of nesting a bunch of switches, which will get pretty ugly fast.  I would suggest this approach which will cover all scenarios.  It will update your existing db (not matter the version) to the current in a step-wise fashion:    (as discussed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6581379/2000151))

```
int curVer = oldVersion;
while ( curVer < newVersion ) {
    curVer++;
    switch ( curVer ) {
        case 2: {
            // Upgrade from V1 to V2
            break;
        }
        case 3: {
            // Upgrade from V2 to V3
            break;
        }
        case 4: {
            // Upgrade from V3 to V4
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Simple,,just have your case conditions in reverse order and dont use break

example in below condition if i value is 3 it will print 3,2,1 if its 4 then 4,3,2,1

`switch(i){
        case 4:
            System.out.println("4");
        case 3:
            System.out.println("3");
        case 2:
            System.out.println("2");
        case 1:
            System.out.println("1");
        }`